# Powershell append text file in loop

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of groups in AD via powershell. I am not exactly sure where to put the Out-File. I want it to read from the csv file and search ad for groups names containing the location then output it to a file and append to the list for each location until it gets to the end.

This is what I have so far

```
Import-Csv "C:\users\alex.piwowar.adm.j2global\desktop\GroupList.CSV" | Foreach-object{
  $Location=$_."Location"

  Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*$Location*"} | Select name
  } | Out-File c:\Group.txt -Append
```

When I run it, it creates a text file but it is blank. If i run just

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*$Location*"} | Select name
```

for each location individually I get results so I know that the problem is with the Out-File

Comment: store the results as a string, and then at the very end of the process, write the string to the end of the file. In this case, you are trying to get output from the forloop, but the `foreach-object` doesn't have a return value, so you are doing all your work, but throwing it out, and then storing the return value of the loop itself to file.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you are calling Out-File after it exits your For loop.  So it should be enough to place that inside the Foreach loop.

It should look something like this:

```
    Import-Csv "C:\users\alex.piwowar.adm.j2global\desktop\GroupList.CSV" |Foreach-object{
 $Location=$_."Location"

  Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*$Location*"} | Select name | Out-File c:\Group.txt -Append
  }
```